# AXB = 0. A, B positive semi-definite. X in range of A $\implies$ X = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a paper concerning the equation AXB = 0. A and B are positive semi-definite. The authors state that the columns of X belong to the range of A and deduce that X = 0. I am struggling to see how this was deduced, could anyone provide any hints?

Edit: A $\neq$ 0, B$\neq$ 0. Furthermore, $X$ can be expressed as $X = S + U$ where the columns of U belong to the null space of $A$.

Edit: The link to the paper is:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221345012_Learning_Output_Kernels_with_Block_Coordinate_Descent.

I am specifically concerned with the proof of Theorem 3.3.

Comment: Consider $B=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "X in range of A"?

Comment: "the columns of X belong to the range of A" Do you want to say by that that column spaces of A and X are the same?

Comment: @miro Not the same, each column of X can be represented as Av for some v.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider e.g. $A=X=I$ and $B=0$. There are perhaps some missing conditions that you have overlooked.

Comment: @miro The identity matrix is positive definite. Hence positive semidefinite.

Comment: According to official definition yes. Wouldn't be more useful to define positive semidefinite matrix through quadratic form >=0 and additional condition of zero determinant? Is there any good reason for the definition allowing to have a subset of positive semidefinite matrices as positive definite?